# Query syntax for GmailApp.search/ searching for multiple words

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to use search on GmailApp. The documentation says that the query syntax has to be similar to the what we use in gmail inbox. However the behavior seems to be different. I am not quite able to get the syntax for searching multiple words ANDed for example, if i search for "vegas trip", i would assume that i should get all mails which has "vegas trip" in it or if not, than at least the ones with both "vegas" and "trip" in it. However, what i get back seems to ignore "vegas" and only operate on second keyword... Is there any formal documentation on the syntax and what/how is supported?

Answer (score 11):

I usually refer to this document for building Gmail Search Queries for Apps Script as well as Gmail Searchbox. It works well as per the documentation.

http://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en